# position not working in percentage

Tags: css

I am trying to create a box, that extends above and bottom from it's background and remain expandable too to accommodate little larger paragraphs too.

I have tried to created 2 overlapping DIVs, one containing background and another containing content, i have shorten the background with `background-size: 100% 90%` and tried to use `top: -5%` to move the content div out towards top, but it's not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/nzM4Y/

If i change the position to `top:-10px` it works, but it will not remain equal on both top and bottom when content will increase.

Comment: Are you updating it via ajax or reloading the page with the new content?

Comment: This will be used in a CMS, so content will be added through backend by user later.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add 50% from top in background image and rest code is fine.

background:url(http://staging.xhtml-lab.com/gray-bg.gif) 0 **50%** no-repeat;

It will work :)

Eg:

```
#landing-bg {
    background:url(http://staging.xhtml-lab.com/gray-bg.gif) 0 50% no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    background-size: 100% 90%;
    margin-top:10%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sushil Raghav, i still need to use top:-5% because i need to overlap the top extended portion above an image. I have updated the jsfiddle to reflect that.